# How to track the users geoposition with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I would like to track the geo-location of users accessing my website.

I believe we can do so approximately using ip addresses. Is there a way to do so using javascript?

Comment: Have you Googled for "JavaScript geolocation" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Geolocation API](http://caniuse.com/#search=geo) (limited browser support, accuracy and precision depend on the browser's ability to work out its location (so is usually better where the browser is running on a device with a GPS)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using HTML 5 Geolocation. See: http://html5demos.com/geo

A good strategy is to use geolocation if its available and fall back to IP address based positioning if it isn't.